# React Navigation: Using single screen component in multiple tab navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to create top tab navigation with two different tabs.

Each tab displays one image - either a Car or a Truck.

What I want to do is use a single screen component rather than the two-component screen (which I have right now). The picture of the tab screen displayed changes based on the active tab.

Is this possible in react-navigation 5.

This is what I have so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function CarScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Image of car</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function TruckScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Image of truck</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Car"
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Car"
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Car' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Truck"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Truck' }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not sure to anderstand your question but few day ago I make a react nativigation app using similar patern with MaterialBottomTabNavigator : https://github.com/samuel3105/react-native-navigation, so if this could help...

Answer (score 1):

You can access the route name by using `props.route.name` and you can change image by using that condition.

I also made a snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/shallow-blueberries

```js
function CarOrTruck({route}) {
  const getImageUrl = (routeName) => {
    if (routeName === 'Car') {
      return 'https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/SONATA-hero-option1-764A5360-edit.jpg'
    } else if (routeName === 'Truck') {
      return 'https://www.volvotrucks.com/content/dam/volvo/volvo-trucks/masters/press-releases/2020/feb/pr-2952-fh/high-res-08A3977-FH-4x2-semi-trailer-long-haul-on-road.jpg';
    } else {
      return 'https://brayve.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/4004/the-secret-history-of-the-google-logo.jpg-23keepProtocol'
    }
  }

  const imageUrl = getImageUrl(route.name);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Image source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={{width: 200, height: 100, resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

So in your 2 , it refers to component={CarOrTruck}

```js
 <Tab.Screen
    name="Car"
    component={CarOrTruck}
    options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Car' }}
/>
<Tab.Screen
    name="Truck"
    component={CarOrTruck}
    options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Truck' }}
/>
```